# How Hash of a String Literal in String Literal Pool Computed?

Tags: java, string, hash

I was seeing the implementation of String class in Java, and the constructor of this goes like this

```
public String(String var1) {
        this.value = var1.value;
        this.hash = var1.hash;
    }
```

So, if you'll do

```
String s1 = "String";
String s2 = new String("String");
```

even though s1 and s2 are two different objects, `s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode()` returns `true` as expected, because in it's constructor, String Class takes hash from it's String literal.
I've deduced that hash of this String literal is computed when String literal is created in String literal Pool, and not when String object is created.
My question is, how and where the hash of this String literal is computed in Java?
is there some native implementation for this?

Comment: Even if there is a native implementation, it will have to behave exactly like [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29). It isn't the best hash algorithm in the world, but it's fixed because [the Javadoc specifies it explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--). Javadoc should always be your first port of call when you want to learn something about the behaviour of a built-in class.

Comment: hashcode only work with values in string. so that's why hashcode is same. but reference is different

Comment: As an interesting(?) aside, in OpenJDK `String.hashCode()` doesn't have a native (intrinsic) implementation, only `equals()`, `compareTo()` and `indexOf()`. But this may change in the future, and other VM implementations are free to do their own thing too, so long as it **behaves exactly like specified**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the [code for String](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java), we see that the value of hash is initially zero.  When hashCode is called, it defaults to the value of hash *unless* it is zero in which case the calculation is performed.  So when is hash calculated before it gets passed in the copy constructor of String?

Simply put, it doesn't.  It copies the value of hash of the passed string, which, if the hash *had* been calculated, would be non-zero.  Otherwise the new string instance takes on a hash value of 0 and both instances could potentially perform the same calculation twice.

It is a reasonable optimization since you wouldn't want to force calculation of the hash code if it isn't necessary.  The real optimization is recycling of string instances to avoid copying in the first place.

Comment: So, my query is if i do str = new String("abc") and again, if i do, str2 = new String("abc") later in my code, this time i'm passing String literal "abc" and not the String object having "abc", so will the hash of str2 be computed again ?

Comment: @Shashi No, the hash is calculated only upon calling hashCode() of that instance.  If you copy a string that has had hashCode called on it, then that string's hash value will be non-zero and it will cause the newly created instance also to have a non-zero value.  Otherwise both will be zero and both will require a calculation of the hashCode.  However it should be noted that this is openJDK.  These are the types of optimization details that may vary from jvm to jvm since they aren't in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29

It is right there in String, will be cached in an internal variable. Admittedly I don't know whether there is some magic in literal strings that sidesteps this implementation.

Comment: I was looking for the code where actual hash of String literal is computed. in the implementation you provided, int h = hash is being used, where hash is extracted out of String literal instead of computing it in String class itself.

Comment: A string literal is an instance of `java.lang.String`, there is nothing special about it.

Comment: Variable `hash` is local, and contains 0 on initialization. That means the `hashCode()` will run and compute the hash first, then store in in `hash`. Also, I *suspect* literals are created straight from byte or char arrays into objects, therefore don't bring their own hash. In any case, in seems what you are looking for is in `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the hash calculation between a literal String and a String instance created by a constructor. Both use String.hashCode().

Literal Strings are pooled by default in a String pool. See the javadoc description of String.intern().